# Prisma.io long text with mysql

Tags: mysql, prisma

I want an alternative for long `Text` type in **MySql** with Prisma

`error: Type "TEXT" is neither a built-in type, nor refers to another model, custom type, or enum.`

I see Only String

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use `String` with either the `@db.Text` or `@db.LongText` mapping, without it the MySql database mapping by default is `varchar(191)`. See [prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#mysql](https://prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#mysql)

```
field String @db.Text
```